# Will calcium chloride still work under a coffee filter?

Tags: dehumidifier

I have some disposable paper coffee filters, shallow glass jars and canning lids. I can use the ring part of the lids to affix the coffee filter over the jar's mouth. I am thinking of putting calcium chloride in a jar like this to prevent it from spilling or creating dust - but will it still be able to dehumidify effectively? Will moist air be able to get through the coffee filter?

Comment: Can water go through coffee filters?

Comment: Without some mechanism to force the air to circulate you're likely to end up with dry air inside the jar and only the most miniscule transfer of moisture through your filter.

Comment: @Gunner Looks like brhans responded to you before I could.